# What is the best way to update profile using chef resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to update the profile using the following chef resource

```
bash 'env_var' do
  code <<-EOH
    echo export APP_ADDR="http://#{node['ipaddress']}:8443" >> /etc/profile
  EOH
  not_if "grep -q APP_ADDR=http://#{node['ipaddress']}:8443 /etc/profile"
end
```

I want to ask if there is a better way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux distros support an `/etc/profile.d/` folder where you can create individual file snippets rather than updating a file in-place. If you do need to update the file in-place, check out the `line` cookbook as it has resources like this but with more fine-grained control.